# Java swing best way to manage button enabled / disable states by criteria

Tags: java, swing

I have a swing application with many buttons. Now, in certain cases they should not be able do anything, so they should be disabled. Each button has a different criteria whether it should be enabled or not. My question is, what is the best way to make sure every button is enabled / disabled when it should be? I do not want to add multiple event listeners to other components that call setEnabled each time.

This would be a (sort of ugly) pseudocode solution for now (written in groovy):

```
  static JButton attachEnabledCriteria(JButton jb, BooleanSupplier p) {
    if (!btnEnabledCriteria.containsKey(jb))
      btnEnabledCriteria.put(jb, p)
    return jb
  }

  private static final Map<JButton, BooleanSupplier> btnEnabledCriteria = new LinkedHashMap<>()

  static {
    Thread.startDaemon("button-updater", {
      while(true) {
        btnEnabledCriteria.forEach { jb, bs -> jb.setEnabled(bs.getAsBoolean()) }
        Thread.sleep(100)
      }
    })
  }
```

Is there a better solution than a criteria-checking repeating loop?

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue. When would the buttons be disabled? Why don't you have an array of `JButton`s (or your custom `JButton` class) and then call `.setEnabled()` on any of them according to your business logic

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity. Not all buttons should be enabled / disabled at the same time and the criteria depend on multiple things.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to loop over the components and check with instanceof for their type and whenever the component is a JButton you can apply your logic. You would want to do something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < getContentPane().getComponentCount(); i++) {
        
        Component c = getContentPane().getComponent(i);
        if (c instanceof JButton){
            
            if("Your logic here"){
                ((JButton) c).setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But when to update? Again, in a thread loop?